# Are model beans singleton in spring?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, scope, singleton

In spring the classes annotated with `@Controller`, `@Service`, `@Repository`, `@Component` act as Spring beans and will be instantiated by Spring container in singleton (Default scope).

Here the model beans are not annotated with any stereo type annotations.

My question here is whether the model beans are singleton or not i.e., if they come under Spring container.

If it is true then, how has the concurrency issue been handled?

Comment: any bean that you create using spring-context is managed by the spring container, you have an option to create a bean as prototype or singleton, not sure what you mean by model beans?

Comment: We usually create bean with setters and getters for example to save user information in db we are creating class called user it has setters and getters to save it in db using orm.

Answer (score 3):

Model attributes, ex. from `@ModelAttribute` annotated parameters, are not beans. They are not managed by the `BeanFactory` / `ApplicationContext`. They are created by the `DispatcherServlet`'s MVC stack and provided to you. There's no concurrency issue (unless you create one) because a Servlet container handles each request in a single thread.

Comment: Even the servlet container handles multithreading the concurreny issue will occur if the two thread tries to access the user object i.e., model object.Because all model attributes are statefull .Please correct me if am wrong

Comment: @sridhar Which two threads? The model object (which ends up being a `HttpServletRequest` attribute) is only available to the request handling thread. If you hand it over to another thread, it's up to you to handle concurrency issues.

Comment: See i have method called addUser(User user) in UserController.
Two HttpRequests hits the addUser method at a time .
Now what will happen??

Comment: @sridhar Each will get a different object.

Comment: Suppose that method as StringBuilder (not synchronized) two threads try to access the stringbuilder in this case the concurrency will occurs am i right?

Comment: StringBuilder is threadsafe, if you use stringbuffer instead which is not thread safe (but synchronized), then you end up with different threads trying to access the same stringbuffer object

Comment: @sridhar Now you're talking about concurrency issues unrelated to the question. Ask another question if you're having those issues.

Comment: In question itself i mentioned that how the concurrency issue have handle ?

Comment: @rahulpasricha I think you were wrong. StringBuffer is threadsafe not stringbuilder.
So code which we are using inside the method of controller should be synchronized if it has to been access two threads at a time .

Comment: @sridhar Yes, as relating to model objects. The answer is there are no concurrency issues coming from Spring or the Servlet API itself. If **you** introduce them, **you** have to handle them. How you do that is entirely use-case dependent.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis can you react for the post which i posted to rahulpasricha

Comment: @sridhar `StringBuffer` has `synchronized` methods, yes. However, if you create the object **inside** a controller method, it is only referenced with that method. Unless you pass to some other thread, there is no issue. Only one thread will be using it.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thanks you are right. But if i created the object globally in controller in this case whether the concurrency will occurs or not ?

Comment: @sridhar Yes. For example, if you have a instance variable, that will be shared by all threads passing through your controller code. That's why it's recommended to either have no instance state (no instance variables) or to have them be thread safe. Thread safety doesn't necessarily mean that everything has to be `synchronized`. It can simply mean they operate on different state and therefore nothing else is shared.